# Vulcanizing a Polymer project on windows

Tags: node.js, polymer

I want to package my component to test it live.

My component lives in the following structure

bower_components/

- core-xxx
- my-project

  - project.html
  - elements.html
- paper-xxx

I installed vulcanize by typing: npm -g install vulcanize

No errors were given.

Now , starting node by: node

And then trying: vulcanize project.html

This returns nothing...

Am I doing something wrong here?

(Using windows 8)

Comment: I solved it. I was not supposed to run vulcanize through node. Just typing vulcanize [filename] worked. However, I also had to extract all the "dependency" link elements into a separate folder and process that.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I was not supposed to run vulcanize through node. Just typing "vulcanize [filename]" worked. However, I also had to extract all the "dependency" link elements into a separate .html document and process that.